# The most effective way to assign unique integer id to a string?

Tags: python, hash

The program that I write processes a large number of objects, each with its own unique id, which itself is a string of complicated structure (dozen of unique fields of the object joined by some separator) and big length.

Since I have to process a lot of these objects fast and I need to reffer to them by id while processing and I have no power to change their format (I retrieve them externally, by network), I want to map their complicated string id to my own internal integer id and further use it for comparison, for transfering them further to other processes, etc.

What I'm going to do is to use a simple dict with keys as string id of the object and integer values as my internal integer id of it.

My question is: is there a better way in Python to do this? May be there is a way to calculate some hash manually, whatever? May be the dict is not the best solution?

As for numbers: there are about 100K of such unique objects in the system at a time, so the integer capacity is more than enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For comparison purposes, you can `intern` the strings and then compare them with `is` instead of `==`, which does a simple pointer comparison and should be as fast as (or faster than) comparing two integers:

```
>>> 'foo' * 100 is 'foo' * 100
False
>>> intern('foo' * 100) is intern('foo' * 100)
True
```

`intern` guarantees that `id(intern(A)) == id(intern(B))` iff `A == B`. Be sure to `intern` any string as soon as it is input. Note that `intern` is called `sys.intern` in Python 3.x.

But when you have to pass these strings to other *processes*, your `dict` solution seems best. What I usually do in such situations is

```
str_to_id = {}
for s in strings:
    str_to_id.setdefault(s, len(str_to_id))
```

> so the integer capacity is more than enough

Python integers are bigints, so that should never be a problem.

Comment: This didn't work for me, when I actually print the `intern` for 2 strings: `featureVal is  cents
Encoded feature value is 4571865856
featureVal is  number_slot
Encoded feature value is 4571867200
featureVal is  bn
Encoded feature value is 4537878648
featureVal is  saudi
Encoded feature value is 4571865856` - note that the word `cents` is exactly the same feature value as `saudi`. The line is `print "featureVal is ",featureVal
        print "Encoded feature value is", id(intern(str(featureVal.encode("utf-8"))))`

Answer (score 5):

How about the `hash` function?

```
In [130]: hash
Out[130]: <function hash>

In [131]: hash('foo')
Out[131]: -740391237
```

There is no need to store hashes (unless you want to): the point is that they are equal for objects that are value-equal (although the reverse may not be true - there are no doubt unequal strings or other objects that hash to the same value; such is the nature of hashing).

If you know the range of your keys (and you probably do), you could also use a perfect hash function generator. This is apparently one for python: http://ilan.schnell-web.net/prog/perfect-hash/

Perfect hashes guarantee that keys within the specified range have a bijective relationship with their hash value.

Comment: Thanks for great link and proposition, Marcin! Collision are what I'm concerned about: I would like to use my own hash function, exploting my knoweledge of key structure, but to handle collisions I would have to implement the whole slots mechanism, while dict() gives it to me for free, even though its internal hashing would probably be more general and thus less effective than I could do for my specific strings.

Answer (score 4):

You could use one of the [hashlib](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html) algorithms to create a cryptographically sound digest of the long message, and then use this as dictionary keys. Example using SHA-256:

```
import hashlib
...
key = hashlib.sha256(longMessage).digest()
```

The chance of collisions is much smaller this way than by using hash(longMessage).

*However*, this could introduce a potentially big overhead. Unless memory usage is a big concern I would simply use the original strings as keys instead.

Answer (score 4):

I've used the following for this purpose:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(lambda: len(d))
>>> d["cats"]
0
>>> d["cars"]
1
>>> d["cats"]
0
```

Answer (score 1):

If they are stored in memory, and you're comparing each string as an object rather than as text I would suggest using `id(string)` to get a unique integer. Alternatively, if you're storing them in a dict you could use a defaultdict with a set of matches and hash them:

```
>>> strings = 'a whole lot of strings which may share a hash'.split()
>>> storage = defaultdict(set)
>>> for s in strings:
...     storage[hash(s)].add(s)
>>> storage[hash('a')]
{'a', 'a'}
```

Exactly how you would implement this depends on how you're using them, but the basic idea should work.  If you could post a specific example of what you're trying to do it might be easier to give a more detailed answer.

Comment: `id` only works for this purpose after interning. Comparing the `id` of two objects is the same as comparing with `is`.

Comment: True. That's why I said compare as objects rather than text. intern would certainly be necessary, then id would give a unique integer.

Answer (score 1):

`dict` is a fine solution.  If you have a way of generating a unique ID based on the string ID, you could have that do double duty as hash function for a custom string class:

```
class ID_String(str):
    cached_hash = None
    def __hash__(self):
        # custom hash code here
        return custom_hash
    def ID(self):
        if self.cached_hash is None:
            self.cached_hash = self.__hash__()
        return self.cached_hash
```