# Pythonic way to increment and assign ids from dictionary

Tags: dictionary, if-statement, python

This seems to be a pretty common pattern:

```
for row in reader:
    c1=row[0]
    if ids.has_key(c1):
        id1=ids.get(c1)
    else:
        currid+=1
        id1=currid
        ids[c1]=currid
```

I want to know if there is a better way to achieve this. As far as single line if statements go, I could do this much:

```
id1=ids.get(c1) if ids.has_key(c1) else currid+1
```

But then I'm stuck with incrementing currid and sticking if the else case was executed and sticking c->id1 into the dictionary if the if condition passed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the ids start from 0:

```
for row in reader:
    id1 = ids.setdefault(row[0], len(ids))
```

(Aside: `has_key` is considered deprecated. Use `x in d` instead of `d.has_key(x)`.)

Comment: Funny; I posted [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9619677/166749) earlier today and actually [used](https://github.com/larsmans/scikit-learn/commit/86f621b1c738bd2b6d50a663b117500eae2fd63f#L1R79) this idiom only yesterday.

Comment: Like I said, common pattern ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind changing how `ids` is defined, then you could go with this (all in the standard library):

```
ids = collections.defaultdict (itertools.count ().next)
```

Usage is then very simple:

```
print (ids["lol"])
```

Comment: nice to know. I'm building a distance matrix so would rather have int ids. have a huge amt of data too.

Comment: Very nice, but this also changes the dict's behavior because it will never again raise a `KeyError`. Still, +1.

Comment: @larsmans: not raising `KeyError`s is the point of `defaultdict`.

Comment: @Sid: This will give integer ids, starting with 0 and then incrementing by 1, as in your example.  But as larsmans said, this will make the dictionary behave somewhat differently, of which you have to be aware if you use it.

Comment: @doublep In my case this would have worked perfectly fine too as the type of ids is not a critical. Thanks.

Comment: @EthanFurman: I know, I'm just pointing out that the semantics of the dict change when one uses this option.

Answer (score 1):

```
currid += c1 not in ids
id1 = ids.setdefault(c1, currid)
```

Comment: This doesn't store the new id.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
id1 = ids.get(cl, currid + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit more pythonyc, with the same semantics:

```
for row in reader:
    c1 = row[0]
    if c1 not in ids:
        currid += 1
        ids[c1] = currid
    id1 = ids[c1]
```